# Clang built on GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, compiler-flags

I was searching online to see  if clang supported reproducible builds. I read that GCC guaranteed reproducible builds using the `-frandom-seed` flag. I wanted to know if clang supports that flag and I could not find anything regarding that.I then came  [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-toolchain@freebsd.org/msg00024.html) which had a statement such as:

> ...two consecutive builds of (GCC-built) Clang

My question is what is GCC built clang ? I am currently aware of only 2 compilers (Microsoft , GCC (Coudl be Cygwin/Mingw flavor) ) and the third one was suppose to be clang. My question is what does clang (GCC built) mean ? Built from source ? I would like to think that clang is a totally different compiler from GCC and Windows. Also [this](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#windows) documentation here states

> Clang has experimental support for targeting “Cygming” (Cygwin /
>   MinGW) platforms.

What does that mean ? Does clang mean that it uses Mingw GCC as a compiler ? What does targeting mean here ?

Comment: Clang was probably built from source using GCC. Clang _is_ a compiler, it can't _use GCC as a compiler_.

Comment: so will clang support -frandom-seed flag ?

Comment: if it's GCC's feature, then no. Read some docs on clang.

Comment: the docs dont mention -frandom-seed so I guess its not available

Comment: @ForceBru, To be fair, Clang supports a heck of a lot of GCC features.

Comment: @chris, that's why on Mac OS we can use `gcc prog.c` while there's no GCC installed. Mac OS uses clang.

Comment: I don't see `-frandom-seed` listed on http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options .  But Clang certainly is a compiler, and does not rely on GCC in general.  The email you found could be summarized as "I built Clang twice, using GCC, and noticed that the binaries weren't identical.  Why not?" -> "GCC uses random symbols in some cases, you need to pass `-frandom-seed` to GCC if you want identical binaries."  Unfortunately, it doesn't answer your actual question.

Comment: So then my question gets back to if if clang supports binary compatibility of generated executable and libraries for windows as mingw and cygwin gcc are capable of doing?

Comment: I don't see `-frandom-seed` listed on http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#command-line-options.  And I can that Clang 3.5.0 doesn't recognize it.  Then again, your real question is whether you can get identical builds from identical sources if you run the compiler at different times.  The answer for GCC is that you need `-frandom-seed` for that.  Clang may not need that option (which would be a great reason not to support it).  Unfortunately, I don't know if it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my mind, this phrase means *clang was built from source using GCC as a compiler*. Then, clang *is a compiler*, so it can't use GCC as a compiler.

Compilers are written in programming languages to be able to compile code written in a programming language. This means, *a compiler can compile a compiler or even itself*.

If you don't know is feature X supported in product Y, please, *read the docs* on product Y. If this feature isn't mentioned, it's not supported and vice versa.